# type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I fix this issue?

Here is my model class

```
@JsonSerializable()
class FollowsModel {
  int userId;

  FollowsModel();

  factory FollowsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map){
    return  _$FollowsModelFromJson(map);
  }
}
```

JSON serializable code

```
FollowsModel _$FollowsModelFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
  return FollowsModel()
    ..userId =  json['userId'] as int;
}
```

This is the code that is bringing problems

```
          followsModel = list.isNotEmpty ? list.map<FollowsModel>((e) => FollowsModel.fromJson(e)).toList(): [];
```

Api response

```
I/flutter ( 3121): Response Text:
I/flutter ( 3121): {"message":"List of users followed by me.","data":[10393]}
```

Comment: could you include sample of your response too?

Comment: I asked for sample of api response.

Comment: @eamirho3ein Please see

Comment: man, I asked for your api response, the one you want too pars it. just print your api response,

Comment: Okay, understood, Just a minute

Comment: @eamirho3ein see now

Comment: where is the list you are looking for?

Comment: I want that list of user IDs

Comment: why it is this: "data":[10393]?

Comment: It's just supposed to be  [10391,15232,], Don't mind that output

Comment: A list of userIDs

Answer (score 1):

Your api response is a `list of int`, but in parse method you expect `Map<String, dynamic>`, so just change those `map` to `int`. Like this:

```
factory FollowsModel.fromJson(int id){
    return  _$FollowsModelFromJson(id);
  }

FollowsModel _$FollowsModelFromJson(int id){
  return FollowsModel()
    ..userId =  id;
}
```